# saving pictures file name as camera ID

Tags: pi-2, camera, raspicam, bash

I have 30 raspberry pi camera modules working in the same network. I am using `pssh -h host.txt raspistill` command to take pictures form all these modules simultaneously where host.txt contains IP addresses of all PIs. The problem is every time these cameras take pictures in random sequence and I'm using time stamp to name the picture files. Here I have 3 questions:

1. how to save pictures' name by the camera ID so I could know that which picture belong to which camera device?
2. how to set camera ID?
3. copy all the pictures from remote raspberry PIs to local machine but with the same name (camera ID).

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [compoundpi](https://compoundpi.readthedocs.io/) as well ... does more or less what you describe, and takes care of file naming for you. If you want absolute control over filename (and everything else), have a look at the [batch clients](http://compoundpi.readthedocs.io/en/release-0.4/batch.html) chapter.

Answer (score 2):

there is alot of ways actually , but nativly , you must know some `bash` basics.

in `terminal` :

`cam_id="camera_1"`

`raspistill -o $HOME\$cam_id`

so i advise you read more about `bash-scripting` and `shell` commands more.

as for the file copying , its depends on the `protocol` you are using is it `web` , `ftp` or network shared folder smb or `samba`.

in that case i advise you to use `wget`.

**useful link :**

[shell & bash basics : How To Read and Set Environmental and Shell Variables on a Linux VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-read-and-set-environmental-and-shell-variables-on-a-linux-vps)

[wget : retrieving files using HTTP, HTTPS and FTP](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I can quite answer all your questions, but pssh (known as `parallel-ssh` on Debian-based systems) can pass the host name to the remote hosts in the **PSSH_HOST** variable. In order to do this, though, in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` of *all* of the remote machines you need to ensure that there is the line:

```
AcceptEnv LANG LC_* PSSH_NODENUM PSSH_HOST
```

(the LANG and LC_* entries were likely there before, and **PSSH_NODENUM** additionally allows you to refer to machines by sequence.)

After restarting the ssh service on each remote machine

```
sudo service sshd restart
```

you should then be able to issue a command like:

```
parallel-ssh -h host.txt 'raspistill -dt -o "${PSSH_HOST}-%d.jpg"'
```

and you get individual files with the hostname and timestamp on each machine. The file *host.txt* contains a list of the hosts you want to operate on, one to a line, in the form `[user@]host[:port]`

To get the remote files to the local machine, I'd use something like `rsync` to keep the local image folders up to date with the remote ones. You might even be able to call it from `pssh` …

Comment: I don't have a working raspistill setup, so I'm not sure if that command line will work exactly. But the `${PSSH_HOST}` bit I have tested, and that's what you need to tell the files apart